# Sql server - Limiting the number of elements returned using select FOR XML PATH command

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, select

Using sql server with FOR XML PATH

Say my XML output is this:

```
<urlset>
  <url>
    <loc>abc</loc>
    <lastmod>efg</lastmod>
    <changefreq>hij</changefreq>
    <priority>kml</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

And I want to have no more than 40,000 rows (row = "url" element)

How can I accomplish this ?

This is my sql :

```
SELECT (SELECT p.documentUrl
               + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), sm.txtId)        AS 'loc',
               CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), m.changedate, 103) AS 'lastmod',
               'daily'                                  AS 'changefreq',
               '0.8'                                    AS 'priority'
        FROM   cms_sitesmaps sm
               INNER JOIN cms_main m
                       ON sm.txtid = m.txtid
               INNER JOIN cms_Packs p
                       ON sm.productcode = p.packCode
        WHERE  IsDeleted = 0
               AND SiteMapName = @SiteMapName
               AND sm.ProductCode = @ProductCode
        FOR XML PATH('url'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT('urlset')) AS 'sitemapxml'
```

Thank you

Comment: You can add `top 40000` in the subquery.

Comment: Ok, its that simple, thanks!

Comment: Do you need to process more than 40000 rows though (perhaps just wrapped in a new `urlset` element?